# Is there a provider for JavaMail which can be put into JNDI and send mail directly without using an MTA?

Tags: jakarta-ee, smtp, jakarta-mail, jndi, war

I have a webapp (Java EE WAR) which has some light duties sending email to the website owner when a form is submitted.  I'm considering hosting it on a PaaS platform, but they don't provide an SMTP server for my use.

What I'd like to find is a provider for JavaMail which will allow me to get a `javax.mail.Session` from JNDI, which simply looks up the MX record of the recipient and sends the mail there, rather than simply queueing it for delivery with a local MTA.

Does anyone know of a little open-source project which does that?

Comment: If the recipient use greylisting (to avoid spam) this simple approach will fail.  Other than that, what is wrong with looking up the MX server yourself in DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm thinking that because:

1. I only ever want to send email to a particular domain; and
2. I control the MX and A records for that domain's email; and
3. that SMTP server is expecting to receive mail for that domain

then I can just configure the standard JavaMail SMTP provider to 'hand off' to the destination MTA.

I'll try it and get back ...

Comment: In other words, use your own server.  That's what I would recommend.  Lacking that, try a public email server, e.g., Gmail.